# How can I get the last Saturday of the month in php

Tags: php

I want to find the date (day of month) of the last Saturday of a given month and year. I know $futureDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($day)); will give me the days in the calendar for a given month / year. What is a good way to get the last Saturday?

I'd like a solution that I could use to apply to any day of the week. For example, I could use the same method to find the date of the last Sunday or Wednesday as well.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$date = new DateTime('now');
$date->modify('last saturday of this month');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```